# Maven: passing requiredProperty values in archetype-metadata.xml through properties or yaml file

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I want to generate maven archetypes by using custom properties through archetype-metadata.xml's requiredProperty -

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="proxy-name">
        <defaultValue>${proxy.name}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="proxy-desc">
        <defaultValue>${proxy.description}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

However, my requirement is to initialize these `requiredProperty` values using **key:value** pairs provided either in a properties file or a yaml file, so that I can get these values injected in `pom.xml` of custom project structure under `archetype-resources`.

```
  <properties>
    <proxy-name>${proxy.name}</proxy-name>
    <proxy-desc>>${proxy.description}</proxy-desc>
  </properties>
```

*I do not want to provide the values to these properties via **command line** or by providing default values. I want the initialization of these property values dynamic based on reading an external properties file when I run the `mvn archetype:generate` command.*

Is this even possible? My apologies in advance if the question seems too vague or really elementary. This is my first experience dealing with custom maven archetypes.

P.S - I have tried using the [yaml-properties-maven-plugin](https://github.com/ozimov/yaml-properties-maven-plugin), however the values still don't get populated in archetype-resources pom.xml, which normally takes values when initializing property values via command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to answer my own question and to help anyone who is into the same problem:

What I did, is to also include an `archetype.xml` in `META-INF/maven` which takes in the resource properties file name to use to substitute custom values in the `archetype-metadata.xml`. Here's how the `archetype.xml` looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype>
    <id>quickstart-archetype</id>
    <sources/>
    <resources>
        <resource>archetype.properties</resource>
    </resources>
</archetype>
```

This way the `yaml-maven-properties` plugin reads the *yaml file* and writes an `archetype.properties` file in the `src/main/resources` folder which also contains the `archetype-resources` folder structure for archetype generation.

Let me know in case anyone needs more clarification on how I achieved this.